# How to create a post with a picture using wordpress json api and phonegap?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api, cordova

I am developing an application in phonegap to publish articles in Wordpress via JSON API, I need to take a picture with my phone and send it as part of the post, how can I do this with javascript (json api)?